# Как правильно сделать проверку на NULL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, filter, lodash

React использую впервые, с JS только знакомлюсь.
Помогите понять как правильно в моем случае сделать проверку на null что бы это сработало.
Я настроил поиск и фильтр по полям, но стоит появится значению null и все ломается.
Проверки по типу if(!result) / if(result === null) / if(result === " ") / if(result === undefined) не дают результата.
Использовал  в проекте Lodash.

```
getFilteredData() {
const { data, search } = this.state;

if (!search) {
  return data;
}

var result = data.filter((payment) => {
  return (
    payment["id"].toString().includes(search.toString()) ||
    payment["status"]
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(search.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
    payment["token"].toString().includes(search.toString()) ||
    payment["currency"].toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
    payment["product"].toString().includes(search.toString()) ||
    payment["redirect_success_url"]
      .toString()
      .includes(search.toString()) ||
    payment["redirect_fail_url"].toString().includes(search.toString()) ||
    payment["amount"].toString().includes(search.toString()) ||
    payment["created_at"].toString().includes(search.toString()) ||
    payment["updated_at"].toString().includes(search.toString()) ||
    payment["extra_return_param"].toString().includes(search.toString()) ||
    payment["operation_type"].toString().includes(search.toString()) ||
    payment["order_number"].toString().includes(search.toString())
    payment["card_masked_number"].toString().includes(search.toString()) ||
    payment["uid"].toString().includes(search.toString())
  );
});

if (!result.length) {
  result = this.state.data;
}

return result;}
```

Вываливается в ошибку TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null.
В некоторых полях есть смешанный тип данных, например ссылка или токен, где есть и цифры и символы, уже спрашивал - посоветовали приводить к строке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае

```
payment["id"].toString().includes(search) ||
```

будет так

```
payment["id"]? payment["id"].toString().includes(search): false ||
```

Comment: Приветствую вас снова, скажите такой вариант подойдет для всех полей ?

Comment: Для всех которые могут быть null

Comment: Проверить просто.

Comment: c id работает, но перестало искать по остальным полям, даже если они не null

Comment: Ну у вас || что значит или. Если вам нужно что складывались фильтры то это и &&

Comment: Если работать c  и &&. В тернарном операторе нужно менять на : true

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз, сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: Подправил ответ если что

Comment: payment["id"]
        ? payment["id"].toString().includes(search)
        : true && payment["status"]
        ? payment["status"].includes(search)
        : true && payment["token"]
        ? payment["token"].toString().includes(search)
        : true;
Прошу прощение за то что вставляю код суда, это не работает :(

Comment: Да правильно. Как вы представляете что одна строка удовлетворяла всем условиям. Изменил на ||

Comment: И думайте что должно быть при каждом  проверяемом search?

Comment: никак не додумаюсь:( возможно намекнете ссылкой на почитать  ?

Comment: Я ее намекают вот вы ввели  21 для поиска понятно что  попадет те которые id либо какая-то строка строка совпадает. А если введёте 21: то в результат могут попасть только те у которых время совпадет и строка какая нибудь.

Comment: А удалив строку вовсе ничего не попадёт

Comment: ещё раз прошу прощения, но это все пока что очень сложно, вы имеете в виду что-то на подобие метода str.match ?

Comment: Да не я имею ввиду что вы ищите совпадение это нормально. Но что должно быть если ищите пустую строку или сложную